# Creating a dictionary from two lists

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dictionary from two lists, the dictionary should do a one-one mapping of each element of the listA to the corresponding element in the listB at the same index ,I have the current output and expected output below, can anyone suggest how to fix this?

```
destination_milestones_gerrit_branches ={}
destination_milestones =['m1','m2','m3']
gerrit_branches = ['b1','b2','b3']
for milestone in destination_milestones:
    print milestone
    for branch in gerrit_branches:
        print branch
        destination_milestones_gerrit_branches[milestone]= branch
print destination_milestones_gerrit_branches
```

Current output:-

```
{'m1': 'b3', 'm3': 'b3', 'm2': 'b3'}
```

Expected output:-

```
{'m1': 'b1', 'm2': 'b2','m3':'b3'}
```

Answer (score 6):

You overwrite your dictionary values every time by doing that double iteration in your loop.

Use `zip` instead:

```
destination_milestones_gerrit_branches = dict(zip(destination_milestones, gerrit_branches))

>>> destination_milestones_gerrit_branches
{'m1': 'b1', 'm2': 'b2', 'm3': 'b3'}
```

If you insist on doing it through a loop, use `enumerate` to get the index of each `destination_milestones`:

```
destination_milestones_gerrit_branches ={}

for i, milestone in enumerate(destination_milestones):
    destination_milestones_gerrit_branches[milestone]= gerrit_branches[i]

>>> destination_milestones_gerrit_branches
{'m1': 'b1', 'm2': 'b2', 'm3': 'b3'}
```

Comment: it works but why is the order messed up meaning ,lets say for 4 elements the output is `{'m4': 'b4', 'm1': 'b1', 'm3': 'b3', 'm2': 'b2'}` instead of `{'m1': 'b1', 'm2': 'b2', 'm3': 'b3', 'm4': 'b4'}`

Comment: That's because dictionaries are unordered (for the most part, except in python 3.6+)

Comment: @user3508811 [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) provides keys order.